Four Circles radii
Consider following constellation of four adjacent circles.

Question:(Initial question doesn't give an unique solution; see edit) Assume we know the radii $R_1,R_2,R_3$. Is there a geometric/synthetic way to determine the radius $R_4$ of the red circle.
Ideas: I tried to draw auxilary lines and embedded the green and blue quadrilaterals. Using that each triangle inside each circle bounded by two blue and one green lines is an isosceles triangle, and from this it's easy to deduce that the opposite angles of the green quadrilateral add up to 180 deg. Note sure if that helps.
#EDIT: As Ethan Bolker & Lieven correctly observed, the radii of the three black circles not alone determine the red circle (neither its radius, not its position). Argument: There is "rolling degree" of freedom for left or right circles.
What, if we impose additional assumption by fixing a concrete angle of blue quadrilateral at at center of $R_2$. Can we then determine $R_4$ and the angles of blue quadrilateral at center of $R_4$?

From the picture it looks to me as if the three given radii do not determine the fourth. You can roll the circle on the left around the bottom circle to make the red circle smaller. If I have misunderstood, please [edit] the question to clarify.

@EthanBolker: You are right, knowing the radii $R_1, R_2, R_3$ not suffice alone to determine uniquely the red circle: neither its radius, not its position. I'm sorry, I just overlooked it. What, it we additionally assume that also the angle of the blue quadriliteral at $R_2$ is given, what can we say about the red circle? Can we then determine it's radius and position? (this would at least eliminate this "rolling degree")

I have a "solution" that I will write tomorrow.

No, in fact you can construct such a diagram for any four given positive lengths $R_1,$ $R_2,$ $R_3$ and $R_4.$ First draw $C_1$ with radius $R_1.$ Choose the centre of $C_2$ anywhere on the circle with the same centre as $C_1$ and radius $R_1+R_2.$ Then around those two centres draw circles with radii $R_1+R_4$ resp. $R_2+R_4,$ which must necessarily intersect in two points. Make one of those points the centre of $C_4.$ Finally draw circles around the centres of $C_2$ and $C_4$ with radii $R_2+R_3$ resp. $R_4+R_3.$ Those circles intersect in 2 points on either side of the line connecting their centres: choose the one on the opposite side from the centre of $C_1$ as the centre of $C_3.$
If in addition the angle at $P_2,$ the centre of $C_2$ is given, then $P_4$ and $R_4$ are uniquely determined by the conditions that:
$$d(P_2,P_4)-d(P_1,P_4)=R_2-R_1$$
$$d(P_3,P_4)-d(P_2,P_4)=R_3-R_2$$
$$d(P_3,P_4)-d(P_1,P_4)=R_3-R_1$$
Each of these conditions separately puts $P_4$ on a hyperbola: the locus of points with a given difference in distance to two fixed points. Only 2 out of the 3 conditions are independent, as the third is actually the sum of the first 2. The intersection of these hyperbolae determines $P_4$ and then $R_4$ is the distance from $P_4$ to any of the 3 other circles.
For an actual construction with ruler and compass, have a look at this question and answer.

I see you are right the radius of red circle is not determined by the radii of the others alone. But what if we impose as input the additional assumption that the angle of the blue quadrilateral is known/ fixed as given input data. Can wethen determine the radius of red circle (and maybe the angle of the blue quadrilateral at the center of the red circle)? I'm sorry for that bad posed question, your answer of course solves the original problem, if you want I willaccept it and post the problem with this additional assumption of the angle at $R_2$ circle as new separate question. Or, could you

maybe loose few words on this new situation. What we then would know about the red circle?

Choosing an angle will determine the problem. Suppose we fix the one at the centre of $C_2.$ Then the centre of $C_4$ is determined by the condition that the difference of its distances to the centres of two pairs of circles is given. The points with a given difference in distance to two given points (where the given difference is less than the distance between those two points) is a hyperbola. The centre of $C_4$ is the intersection point of two hyperbolae (actually three, but the third equation is a linear combination of the other two).

On "Then the centre of $C_4$
is determined by the condition that the difference of its distances to the centres of two pairs of circles is given": You mean that the centers for any two of the given three black circles? So if I understand you correctly, you form the first hyperbola wrt differences to centers of eg $C_1$ and $C_2$ and the second with $C_2$ and $C_3$, and intersect them, that's the center point of $C_4$ we are looking for, right, or do I misunderstand your point? Moreover, in turn to know these distances we have to already know the radius of $C_4$. But how to determine it?

Your understanding is correct, except for the assumption that we have to know $R_4$ in advance. The difference in distance to the centres of $C_1$ and $C_2,$ for instance, is $(R_2+R_4)-(R_1+R_4),$ i.e., the unknown $R_4$ drops out.

Here is an "algebraic understanding" of the issue.
It uses the Cayley-Menger determinant which, equalized to $0$, gives a relationship between the mutual distances $d_{ij}$ of four points in the plane :
$$\det\pmatrix{
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 &  0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{14}^2\\
1 &  d_{12}^2 & 0  & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2\\
1 &  d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0 & d_{34}^2\\
1 &  d_{14}^2 & d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2 & 0
} = 0\tag{1}$$
Here, contact conditions yield $d_{ij}=r_i+r_j$ but for $d_{13}$ that we name $d$, Let us plug these relationships into (1) and take for example $r_1=r_2=r_3=1$. The expansion of the determinant gives :
$$-2d^2(d^2r_4^2 +2d^2r_4 +d^2 -16 r_4^2 -32 r_4)=0$$
from which the following expression can be deduced :
$$d = 4 \frac{\sqrt{r_4^2 + 2r_4}}{r_4 + 1}\tag{2}$$
The graphical representation of (2) is as follows :

On this figure, one can observe

the presence of a horizontal asymptote attesting that the closest distance $d$ is to $4=1+2+1$ (extreme case where circles $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are in a row giving the degenerate cases of a circle $C_4$ with infinite radius), the largest is the value or $r$,

on the left, the stopping point (little red point) with coordinates $(2 \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-1,2)$ corresponds to another extreme case : the configuration were $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are mutually tangent.


SAGE program :
 var('r1 r2 r3 r4 d')
 r1=1
 r2=1
 r3=1
 CM=matrix([
 [0,1,1,1,1],
 [1,0,(r1+r2)^2,d^2,(r1+r4)^2],
 [1,(r1+r2)^2,0,(r2+r3)^2,(r2+r4)^2],
 [1,d^2,(r2+r3)^2,0,(r3+r4)^2],
 [1,(r1+r4)^2,(r2+r4)^2,(r3+r4)^2,0]])
 show(CM)
 dCM=expand(CM.det())
 print(dCM)
 s=solve(dCM,d,multiplicities=False) # explicit expression d=f(r4)
 print(s[1])
 g=implicit_plot(dCM,(r4,0,4),(d,0,5))
 show(g)

